# Splitting a column and extracting from it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe all_data, where the address column's head has been pasted below.

```
all_data['Address'].head()

0             Brocklebank Ground, Torver, LA21 8BS
1                 23 Leigh Street, Aspull, WN2 1QQ
2    Dewsland, Ponthenry Road, Pontyates, SA15 5TY
3               1 Croft Close, Wainfleet, PE24 4DT
4                 3 Landor Avenue, Killay, SA2 7BP
Name: Address, dtype: object
```

I am attempting to extract just the postcode to put it into a new column:

```
all_data['Postcode'] = all_data['Address'].str.split(',')[-1]
```

I am receiving the following error message:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that most `Series` vectorised string operations must be preceded by the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor, which is also the case when taking slices of strings. So you're missing a `str` after the `str.split` to be able to slice the lists.

```
df['Address'].str.split().str[-1]

0    8BS
1    1QQ
2    5TY
3    4DT
4    7BP
Name: Address, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `applymap()` when needed to extract info or apply functional changes from/to each element

```
postals = all_data['Address'].head().apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: ahh! my bad, I took all_data['Address'] to be a dataframe instead of Series. apply() should do Series.